# Page refresh after login?

Tags: javascript, php, html, page-refresh

I am trying to get my page to refresh after login this is the format of my index.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
    // let the user access the main page  
    // i have made the main content with jquery mobile framework 
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    // let the user login
       include "login.php";

}
else
{
    // display the login form
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
                <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Inside my login.php

```
<?php

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['email'];
        $uid = $row['u_id'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
        $flag=1;

    header("Location: http://5aday.dihops.net/index.php");
//        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;index.php\">";
//header("Refresh: 2; url=http://5aday.dihops.net/index.php");
    // THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK 
      }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
?>
    }
    ?>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. But once the user gives his username and password and submits it .... I get a blank page. and the user has to manually refresh the webpage to see the content of the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the link](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm) mentioned the header(location) must be placed at the top of the page ... So I rearranged the if conditions ....

I added this at the top of the index.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
   include "login.php";


} ?>
```

then  in the body  i added the other if statements

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
    // let the user access the main page  
    // i have made the main content with jquery mobile framework 
}else 
else
{
    // display the login form
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
                <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
}
```

That has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**You have no content under:**

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
    // let the user access the main page  
    // i have made the main content with jquery mobile framework 
}
```

So.. when you log in, there's nothing to see.

It doesn't seem there's any HTML elements for JavaScript to grab a handle on and edit either. Unless you're using JavaScript to then create elements from scratch. If so, have you checked that the JavaScript has even loaded? Also, check for errors in the console.

Comment: There is content .. i just did not add it .. in the explanation ..  the content is displayed when i manually refresh the page

Comment: only the HTML content is not loaded .... JS is loaded .... and no errors on console ....

Comment: So, is there any HTML within that if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
    echo "Welcome".$_SESSION['Username'];
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    // let the user login
       include "login.php";

}
else
{
    // display the login form
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
                <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: no need of `isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])` when you are using `!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])`

Comment: There is content .. i just did not add it .. in the explanation .. the content is displayed when i manually refresh the page –

Answer (score 0):

Try using **PHP_SELF** for redirect the same page

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

it might help

Answer (score -1):

Stay page after Login, Refresh page. try JAVASCRIPT in php

`echo "<script>window.location.replace('/')</script>";`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).